# "qui fait de" or "fait de"?

Tags: grammaire, orthographe

I have encountered the phrase:

*Soient K la sous-catégorie pleine de E formée des objets qui peuvent être trivialisés par un objet galoisien, et S la sous-catégorie pleine de E formée des sommes directes d'objets de K. S est un topos localement galoisien, et l'inclusion S → E **qui fait** de S un groupoïde fondamental de E.*

I suspect it should be changed to

*Soient K la sous-catégorie pleine de E formée des objets qui peuvent être trivialisés par un objet galoisien, et S la sous-catégorie pleine de E formée des sommes directes d'objets de K. S est un topos localement galoisien, et l'inclusion S → E **fait** de S un groupoïde fondamental de E.*

Am I right?

Comment: Can you paste the whole sentence ? Both can make be correct, it all depends on what is coming before and after this phrase.

Comment: Soient $K$ la sous-catégorie pleine de $E$ formée des objets qui peuvent être trivialisés par un objet galoisien, et $S$ la sous-catégorie pleine de $E$ formée des sommes directes d'objets de $K$. $S$ est un $\U$-topos localement galoisien, et l'inclusion $S \to E$ qui fait de $S$ un groupoïde fondamental de $E$.

Comment: Thanks - I highly recommend to edit the question and add sentence in full. I must confess this is double Dutch to me... It might be obvious to you, but I (tentatively) understand that $S$ is NOT "l'inclusion $S to E$", correct ? That will indicate if I understand correctly the statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are right. There is no way to make this sentence work.

Here are (simplified) alternatives (the first one is yours, the third one is from cglacet's comment):

> Soient K un ensemble de trucs venant de E, et S un ensemble de machins déduits de K. S est un chose, et l'inclusion S → E **fait** de S un bidule de E.

> Soient K un ensemble de trucs venant de E, et S un ensemble de machins déduits de K. S est un chose, et l'inclusion S → E (est) **ce qui fait** de S un bidule de E.

> Soient K un ensemble de trucs venant de E, et S un ensemble de machins déduits de K. S est un chose, et **c'est** l'inclusion S → E **qui fait** de S un bidule de E.

Comment: "c'est l'inclusion de X qui fait de S un bidule de E" would also be correct. The inclusion of this rule changes S.

Comment: @cglacet Indeed, suggestion added, Thanks.